# Port of Entry Munich for a Visa D issued by Austrian embassy

Tags: schengen, austria, munich

I have seen lot of port of entry queries in the stackexchange website. I have been issued National D visa from Austrian Embassy in India. On the visa sticker, infront of **Valid for** it has mentioned as **AT** which stands for **Austria** according to my understanding.[image]

Does that mean I need to enter schengen territory from Austria. I am confused as some people say that I need to enter from Austria as it has not mentioned **SCHENGEN STAATEN**

Comment: Not AT source, but here's DE's official source on this: https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/18-schengeneinreised/606726 Same rules apply to AT too.

Answer (score 8):

> Valid for it has mentioned as AT which stands for Austria according to my understanding.

Yes, that is correct.

> Does that mean I need to enter schengen territory from Austria.

No, a D-Visa may also be used as a C-Visa for the **other** member states. This was, in the past, entered as a **D+C** but since most were issued that way it was simplified.

Transit was always allowed in the past (when there as no **+C**), but now you can stay as a normal visitor on your way the the issuing country.

The **SCHENGEN STAATEN** term is only used for C-Visa's.